# Project Dependencies in WiX Installer MSI

Tags: .net, wix, nuget

Very new to WiX but having an issue I can't resolve.
I have a simple console application, I have a simple Wix Installer.
I have followed the basic guides to install my console application.
The software appears to have installed correctly but it is missing a library that I have included in my console application.

The error I am getting is:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'FluentCommandLineParser, Version=1.4.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken
=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

This 'FluentCommandLineParser' is simply a library I am using that I installed to the project using the Nuget Package Manager.

Do I have to reference each individual library that the console application is using? If so, how do I do this?

I attempted to resolve by adding the FluentCommandLineParser.dll from the project debug/bin folder as a reference in the WiX installer project but it spits that back on build.

Comment: Yes, you have to add every file used by your project to the installer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the FluentCommandLineParser.dll as a component in your installer if you want it included in the install.

Since you added it with nuget it is probably added as a reference with "Copy Local = True" so you can pretty easily add it to your install.

Just add a new component

```
<Component Id="FluentCommandLineParser.dll" Guid="*">
    <File Id="FluentCommandLineParser.dll" KeyPath="yes" Source="$(var.ProjectNameHere.TargetDir)FluentCommandLineParser.dll" />
</Component>
```

and that should add the dll to your installer.

[Here](http://wixtoolset.org/documentation/manual/v3/votive/votive_project_references.html) is a link that explains and defines all the available preprocessor variables associated with a project reference.

Comment: FantasticThank You